# MediaPlayer start->stop->start for MIDI files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am seeing a problem with MediaPlayer, trying to do the next sequence start()->stop()->start() for MIDI files gives me an error.

By looking at the [MediaPlayer state diagram,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) the sequence should work with the next code:

```
void experiment() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
    Context context = this;
    int resid = R.raw.teddybear;
    String packageName = getResources().getResourcePackageName(resid);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/"  + resid);
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    mp.stop();
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
```

Here is the error is get from the call to the second prepare:

java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFD

This problem does not exist for other sound files.

Is anyone experiencing this also? Am i doing something wrong?

I am not trying to find walk-around - got plenty :)

Things tried:

- removing the stop and stop&prepare&start allows this stream to be played.
- I've heard that the MediaPlayer is not immediately get updated for its state, so i added sleeps between the methods - still same issue.
- Changing the file type solved the issue.
- trying several MIDI file yield the same result.
- registering an OnError also did not worked - he was not called

Can it be that this is a bug?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you said:Changing the file type solved the issue.
2. Try SoundPool